# Kerberos with AuthnProviderAlias

Tags: apache-2.2, kerberos

I was configuring some AuthnProviderAliases today and I want to add kerberos to it. The problem is that when I added kerberos apache wouldn't restart and I got the following error in my syslog:

> May  3 15:27:09 Himeji kernel: [18882.364760] apache2[13774]: segfault at 4 ip b72dacdd sp  bfd4f5f0 error 4 in mod_authn_alias.so[b72da000+2000]

I have followed the syntax on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_alias.html#authnprovideralias and I have the following for ldap which give no errors:

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldapa>  
    AuthLDAPBindDN cn=apache,cn=Users,dc=samba,dc=my,dc=domain
    AuthLDAPBindPassword Test123
    AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://192.168.142.1:636/dc=samba,dc=my,dc=domain?sAMAccountName"
    AuthType Basic 
</AuthnProviderAlias>
```

And the following for kerberos:

```
<AuthnProviderAlias kerberos kerb>
    AuthType Kerberos
    KrbMethodNegotiate on
    KrbMethodK5Passwd off

    KrbSaveCredentials off
    KrbAuthRealms SAMBA.MY.DOMAIN
    Krb5Keytab  /etc/apache2/http.keytab
</AuthnProviderAlias>
```

However the kerberos part doesn't work. Is it because kerberos is not a baseProvider?

Comment: What do you want to do? Auth via ldap or kerberos?